# Using #ifdef inside an array?

Tags: c, arrays, conditional-compilation, misra

I have an array of callback functions. One function should only be used when "SOMETHING" is defined. Is it correct to have an #ifdef inside an array, like:

```
void (*const array[])(void) =
{
    function_callback1,
    function_callback2,
    function_callback3,
    function_callback4,

    #if defined ( SOMETHING)
    function_callback5
    #endif
};
```

The array is defined within a header file as:

```
extern void (*const array[5])(void);
```

I got a MISRA violation:

> "Array has fewer initializers than its declared size. Default
>   initialization is applied to the remainder of the array elements"

Comment: Are you sure the real code doesn't say e.g. `[5]` instead of `[]`? That would explain the error message, which mentions the "declared size" of the array, but your array doesn't have a declared size.

Comment: You can surely do this. The error is due to something else.

Comment: @tuple_cat : Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that the size of array is defined with 5

Comment: With conditional compilation (e.g. `#ifdef`), you simply have to ask yourself two questions:  (1) Does it make sense if the code is included?  And (2) Does it make sense if the code is excluded?  You forgot to ask question (2).  If the code is excluded, then you're missing an initializer, right?  There's no mystery here.  You simply need to provide a dummy value in that case, such as `NULL`.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `SOMETHING` is not defined? Do you want the array to have size 4, or the last element to be `NULL`, or the last element to be something else?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. This will indicate to the community that  you found a solution and will give some reputation to you and the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple, use `#else` and a NULL pointer if `SOMETHING` isn't defined:

```
#if defined ( SOMETHING)
function_callback5
#else
NULL
#endif
```

And both definition and declaration should be defined the same way, using the size constant:

```
void (*const array[5])(void) = {...
extern void (*const array[5])(void);
```

---

If the size of the array is also dependent on SOMETHING, then define another macro:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
    #define ARRAY_SIZE 5
#else 
    #define ARRAY_SIZE 4
#endif
```

Comment: but if SOMETHING isn't defined I have to use already the other function callbacks mentioned in the array, or I misunderstood something?

Comment: @milexy86 what in the world are you talking about?  If `SOMETHING` isn't defined, then you need to supply the missing initializer.  The array isn't going to shrink, since your declaration is forcing it to have 5 elements.  You have two choices:  (1) pad with `NULL` or (2) make the array self-sizing, so that it's only 4 elements if `SOMETHING` isn't defined.  Make your choice, then fix your bug.

Comment: @TomKarzes: You are right, I misinterpreted something by myself. The solution with  (2) will be used and it works. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TomKarzes and @tuple_cat.
It was my fault. I was to quick by reading the code (which is written by someone other) and didn't pay attention to the header files.

So the size of the declared array is in real:

```
array extern void (*const array[AMOUNT_OF_CALLBACK_FUNCTIONS])(void)
```

where:

```
 typedef enum
 {
    FUNCTION1 = 0,
    FUNCTION2,
    FUNCTION3,
    FUNCTION4,
    #if defined ( SOMETHING)
    FUNCTION5,
    #endif
    AMOUNT_OF_CALLBACK_FUNCTIONS
  }enum_t;
```

So, on this way I have the correct size of the array

Comment: You can just have a simple define whose value changed dependin if SOMETHING is defined. This way you don't have to bother with enumerators. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37541921/4082723